# Saddle point problem (KKT) with block-diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-linear-algebra, nonlinear-optimization

Consider the following saddle point problem originating from an interior-point method algorithm:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{H} & \mathbf{A}^{T}\\
\mathbf{A} & \mathbf{0}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{x}\\
\mathbf{y}
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{f}\\
\mathbf{g}
\end{bmatrix},$$ where  $\mathbf{H}$ is a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix, and $\mathbf{A}$ is a full rank matrix.

How can the solution of this linear system take advantage of the fact that $\mathbf{H}$ is block diagonal:
$$\mathbf{H}=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{H}_{1} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0}\\
\mathbf{0} & \mathbf{H}_{2} & \mathbf{0}\\
\mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{H}_{3}
\end{bmatrix}?$$ If each block $\mathbf{H}_{i}$ were positive definite, than the *Schur complement* approach could be used, where $\mathbf{H}^{-1}$ could then be efficiently computed by inverting each block matrix $\mathbf{H}_{i}$.

The problem is small to medium scale (i.e., 50 to 400 unknowns). I am not sure if a direct sparse solver would be suitable for such problem sizes. Currently I use the null-space approach where a linear system involving the reduced Hessian $\mathbf{Z}^{T}\mathbf{H}\mathbf{Z}$, where $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{Z}=\mathbf{0}$.

Comment: 400 unknowns is not a challenge for any linear solver. Unless you want to solve millions of such problems per second...

Comment: Yes, the overall problem consists of solving thousands to millions of such linear systems for every time step in a flow simulation.

Comment: What does change in the sequence of these systems? Only the right-hand side, matrix, structurally/numerically, only a certain block?

Comment: The **H** matrix and right-hand side vector change every iteration of the interior-point method, but the diagonal block structure of **H** is preserved. The matrix **A** is **always** the same.